# GPUImageView Black When ViewController Reloaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

Using the code below (in viewDidLoad), when I first segue from another view to this still camera view (a button press), everything works fine. Then I send out a delegate and have this view dismissed from the previous view.

But, when I press that button on the first view again to show the camera view again, the screen is black. I've changed properties to instance variables, made sure the preview view existed at every step, etc.

But, when I take a picture (even when the screen is black and it's registering focus and exposure activity and responsive to touch) and display a modal view displaying the image for review, I do indeed see what I should have been seeing. And when I dismiss the modal, the camera view works just fine again with NO black.

So, what am I missing here? It's got to be something simple in the framework, IB, storyboard, etc. Thanks!

```
stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
stillCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;

UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank-1x1.png"];
sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
[sourcePicture processImage];

filter = [[GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter alloc] init];
[(GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter *)filter setColorToReplaceRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0];
[(GPUImageChromaKeyBlendFilter *)filter setThresholdSensitivity:0.37f];

[stillCamera addTarget:filter];
[sourcePicture addTarget:filter];

[filter addTarget:videoPreviewView];
[stillCamera startCameraCapture];
```

Comment: Having this exact same problem. GPUImageView contents are black, but I can see that image data is moving correctly through the filter chain, as I can store the resulting UIImage and save it to photo roll. Blackness never shows the first time the view controller appears and not every time it is shown again (waiting a bit longer before showing it again seems to make it less likely to fail).

Comment: After displaying the viewcontroller containing the gpuimageview and dismissing it a few dozen times I eventually managed to have a crash too. Might be a hint: http://i.imgur.com/4RK2qkb.png

Comment: I found this only happens if I have a GPUImageView in my scene and refer to via a referencing outlet and then give that reference to [self.filter addTarget:(GPUImageView *)self.gpuImageView]; If instead I make the root view (?) of the ViewController a GPUImageView and then use that instead in [self.filter addTarget:(GPUImageView *)self.view]; it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to read this thread carefully and this comment specifically : https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/130#issuecomment-5936685 . Hope it helps you too.

Comment: I peppered that code (prepareForImageCapture) in all permutations and mostly I got malloc double free errors in destroyFilterFBO in the framework code. What worked was Bemmu's suggestion to make the imageView the root view of the view controller instead of the image view being a subview. IMHO, that should not matter, I may want a viewfinder as a subview somewhere within another view.